# IllegalArgumentException (@WindowManagerGlobal:findViewLocked:425) {main}

Tags: android

My application getting crashed due to `Illegal Argument Exception (@Window Manager Global : find View Locked:425) {main}`.

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Add your code and logcat error log to the question.

Comment: Show your code, please

Comment: iam not getting this type of crash while testing the application in pre-production environment.This exception got from play store crash report.

Comment: @saranya me too had the same problem did you found any solution for the issue.